# Is possible to edit the size of the image shown in the gutter?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the extension: [`Image preview`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kisstkondoros.vscode-gutter-preview) to show a preview of images when you hover the mouse on its path.

Does someone know if it's also possible to edit the size of the picture in the gutter when there's enough space to it.

[image]

To when the gutter has enough space it be shown like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the extension is `paste-image`? I'm not familiar with it but seems like it's for pasting images, not sowing a preview. Maybe do you mean [Image preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kisstkondoros.vscode-gutter-preview&WT.mc_id=devcloud-22498-buhollan)?

Comment: @MoshFeu  Yea image preview, i found the option `gutterpreview.imagePreviewMaxHeight` but it only increase the size of the thumbnail, you know if is also possible to change the image in the gutter?

Comment: What do you mean `change the image`? The image presented by its path, no? How'd you want it to be displayed?

Comment: @MoshFeu i mean the image size in the gutte, to when the gutter has enought space it be shown like this: https://i.imgur.com/BTikdXW.png